# SQL - CASE WHEN - Data displayed on separate rows after transposing

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, transpose, case-when

I am trying to transpose column data into separate columns. (Note that I can not use the Pivot function or dynamic SQL).

The source table has three columns (year, city, data1).

I am trying to transpose the column 'city' into separate columns for the purpose of comparing the data for selected cities.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT  t.year, 
   CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' THEN t.data1 END) SF, 
   CASE WHEN city = 'Paris' THEN t.data1 END) PAR, 
   CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN t.data1 END) NYC
FROM t
WHERE city IN ('San Francisco', 'Paris', 'New York')
GROUP BY t.year, t.data1
ORDER BY t.year
```

The result is the following table.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s34uc.png)

The problem is that the row 'year' is duplicated several times, while I'd like the data to be displayed on one single 'year' row for all the cities selected. Otherwise I can not plot any line chart.

Any help appreciated.

Table Input Sample:

```
+------+---------------+-------+
| year |     city      | data1 |
+------+---------------+-------+
| 2001 | San Francisco | 15.25 |
| 2001 | New York      | 10.93 |
| 2001 | Paris         | 11.37 |
| 2002 | San Francisco |    15 |
| 2002 | Paris         | 11.87 |
| 2002 | New York      | 11.25 |
| 2003 | Paris         | 11.91 |
| 2003 | New York      |  9.84 |
| 2003 | San Francisco | 15.43 |
| 2004 | New York      | 10.39 |
| 2004 | San Francisco | 15.37 |
| 2004 | Paris         | 11.34 |
| 2005 | Paris         | 11.55 |
| 2005 | New York      | 10.68 |
| 2005 | San Francisco | 15.17 |
+------+---------------+-------+
```

Output Table after using CASE WHEN or MAX/SUM(CASE WHEN)

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| year |  sf   |  par  |  nyc  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2001 | 15.25 |       |       |
| 2001 |       |       | 10.93 |
| 2001 |       | 11.37 |       |
| 2002 |    15 |       |       |
| 2002 |       | 11.87 |       |
| 2002 |       |       | 11.25 |
| 2003 |       | 11.91 |       |
| 2003 |       |       |  9.84 |
| 2003 | 15.43 |       |       |
| 2004 |       |       | 10.39 |
| 2004 | 15.37 |       |       |
| 2004 |       | 11.34 |       |
| 2005 |       | 11.55 |       |
| 2005 |       |       | 10.68 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Desired Output Format (all data displayed per year on a single row):

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| year |  sf   |  par  |  nyc  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2001 | 15.25 | 11.37 | 10.93 |
| 2002 |    15 | 11.87 | 11.25 |
| 2003 | 15.43 | 11.91 |  9.84 |
| 2004 | 15.37 | 11.34 | 10.39 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: What would you expect for when there's multiple data1 per year & city? A sum, perhaps?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function*

```
SELECT  t.year, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' THEN t.data1 END) SF, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN city = 'Paris' THEN t.data1 END) PAR, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN t.data1 END) NYC
FROM t
WHERE city IN ('San Francisco', 'Paris', 'New York')
GROUP BY t.year
ORDER BY t.year
```

**Note**

If there are multiple `data1` on `city` you can try to use `SUM` instead `MAX`

Comment: the results still show data1 for the same year 3 times (example: 1750 SF data1a, 1750 NYC data1b, 1750 PAR data1c). Basically, I'd like to have the data1 for each city on only 1 single 'year' row. To clarify, I'm not trying to sum up the data1, as each rows in the data1 column is different from one another.

Comment: @euclideans Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I've edited the question to add sample input and output tables.

Comment: Where is your  year `2003` and `2004` in your sample data?

Comment: And my query work good https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ZTm3uSVyNC1434pMMFEWr/0  My `group by` column is difference from your. I only `GROUP BY t.year`

Comment: I just added data for 2003, 2004, 2005

Comment: Yes! It worked with your db-fiddle script. I'm not sure why I wasn't able to reproduce using your SO script in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using sum function

```
SELECT  t.year1, 
            SUM((CASE WHEN city = 'San Francisco' THEN t.data1 END)) SF,
            SUM((CASE WHEN city = 'Paris' THEN t.data1 END)) PAR, 
            SUM((CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN t.data1 END)) NYC
FROM t
WHERE city IN ('San Francisco', 'Paris', 'New York')
GROUP BY t.year, t.data1
ORDER BY t.year
```

Comment: What's your answer difference between yours and mine?

Comment: group by clause